# Reading Google Drive Form file with Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I currently have several Google Form files in a specific folder on my Drive account. I am able to create a list of Google File objects and iterate over them like this.

```
        for (File f : formFiles) {


            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
            System.out.println(f.getId());
            System.out.println(f.getTitle());
            System.out.println(f.getMimeType());
            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
            System.out.println("  ");

        }
```

What I would like to do is read all rows and columns of the form file. My first thought was to download them, but the f.getDownloadUrl() returns a null value. The mime type for the above files is "application/vnd.google-apps.form"

Any help in working with Google Forms would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

As with all Google native document formats, you can't use the `downloadUrl` field to download their content. Instead, you should check the `exportLinks` collection to export the form in one of the supported formats:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents